# Listview --> ViewCell --> StackLayout: Not the whole content shows up

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Edit: I was able to solve the problem by adding "HasUnevenRows="True" to the ListView. No clue why it works, but hey, the problem is gone ;D

Edit2: From the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/):

> Application developers will find that the easiest and least error-prone way to automatically size list view rows for content is: first, to set the ListView.HasUnevenRows property to true;

I implemented the following Listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
                      Refreshing="ListView_Refreshing">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding MyObjectValue1, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}" />
                                <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding MyObjectValue2}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding MyObjectValue3}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Content of the ListView in C#:

```
ListView.ItemsSource = listOfMyObject;
```

Note: Image is processing fine, no worrys about that.

Problem: When I deploy my app, only the image is showing up in a normal-sized listview-cell. The two labes are not visible. What I wanna achieve:

```
------------------
|       Pic      |
|      Label1    |
|      Label2    |
|                |
| Next List Entry|
|       ...      |
------------------ //Yes it is a small phone with the shape of a square cuz I am lazy ;D
```

How can I achieve that?

Cheers!

Comment: i found something that it seems to be what you want! [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

Comment: Thank you! But I encountered some problems with it: I have a StackLayout (HeightRequest="300") and inside of it the Image with Aspect="AspectFit". Problem is, that the Image doesnt scales up to fit the parent (-> StackLayout)..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding MyObjectValue1, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}" /> 
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">                              
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding MyObjectValue2}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding MyObjectValue3}" />
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
```